# Carregamento do M2M muito lenta no django

Tags: python, django

Em algumas tabelas utilizo many to many, e à medida que o banco foi crescendo o tempo de carregamento dele esta aumentando (o que é obvio), consegui uma alternativa para o carregamento, que e o raw_id_fields, porem ele não supre a demanda como desejado, se o raw id exibisse o "nome" ao invés do id seria perfeito.
Há alguma alternativa para melhorar o carregamento do m2m ?

```
apensos = models.ManyToManyField(Processo, blank=True, default=None, related_name="Apensos")
```

Esse e um exemplo do uso, em todos os outros o uso e basicamente o mesmo, puxando os dados da tabela processos.

E no admin.py uso:

```
raw_id_fields = ("apensos",)
```

Comment: Pode mostrar como você está fazendo? Uma versão simpliicada dos seus models (so os models relacionados, os imports, e pode tirar os campos desncessários) - além do que está usando para "carregar o banco" - é um script? Usa um arquivo CSV com os dados??

Comment: editei o post adicionando amigo. Esqueci de mencionar que uso o admin do django